# How to expand a tree node in Selenium declared with a span tag

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing some Selenium tests in Python and I'm stuck in a situation:

So, I'm trying to click in an icon what expand an tree node with some check boxes, but when I open the code file or just inspect the element I found an ' ' element declared with a class.I have tried to click on xpath element or css but don't expand that stuff :/

Here's the code line of where I'm trying to click:

```
<span class="ui-tree-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
```

Someone could help?

Comment: Share your code along with error message

Comment: I already tryied some other stuff like as I wrote in the question but I don't quote my searches there and It's my fault, okay? Thank you for send me that question, I reading now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following :

- `xpath` as :

  ```
  "//span[@class='ui-tree-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e']"
  ```

  > OR
- `css` as :

  ```
  "span.ui-tree-toggler.ui-icon.ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
  ```